# Kinect v2, can I set which two persons to track?

Tags: c++, kinect-sdk

Microsoft states that Kinect can recognize six people and track two, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973074.aspx#ID4EY

Is it possible to use the Kinect SDK to manually set which two persons are to be tracked? Or is this already set, e.g. the first two people to be recognized or the two persons closest to the camera?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Kinect skeletal tracking allows the application to choose the skeleton to track among the six users recognized in the field of view.
By default, skeletal tracking will select the first two recognized users in the field of view.

Read more at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131025.aspx#Active_User_Tracking